# Azure blob storage: Where is the "upload" option in the portal?

Tags: azure

The azure portal always feels like a black hole where a 3 min task takes me 45 min. (No wonder I mostly use AWS.)

Puzzle of the day:

- Create blob storage container
- Cannot find way to upload file
- Tried the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, just got errors n stuff.
- Azure Management Studio (commercial app) worked to upload, but would rather not depend on $$ app.
- There has to be a way to upload within azure portal, right? (it has a download option). What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: There is no upload option within the portal and that is by design.

To access the container requires the appro keys and access. The portal is not authenticated to the azure infrastructure that way, so write operations are not allowed.

The portal is misleading, because download IS available, but that is the case because this container has public read access.... so the azure portal makes the files available.

The simple answer to the whole conundrum is to publish the container as a file share, and use plain jane file copy operations to copy files up to the share.

I tried to use the Azure Storage Explorer, but only got errors and no path forward. I installed Azure Management Studio (the free demo) and it worked great.

So problem solved, after 30 min of poking it.

(It would have been OK if the above were somehow communicated better by the portal instead of requiring so much thinking. Though I understand it now, it is not obvious why the azure console would have the ability to list and download files, with no ability to upload.)

Comment: Whilst the first part of the answer is correct, I wouldn't reccomend setting up your blob storage as a file share unless  you really need a file share. This would switch from using Blob Storage to Azure files (SMB on top of blob), which adds performance and security overhead you likely do not need. Your best bet to upload is using tools like Azure Storage Explorer (if your getting errors post a question on that, be glad to help), Az Copy as mentioned below or PowerShell

Comment: @Sam I tried azure storage explorer and could not make it work at all. Set up demo of a commercial tool which worked. Didn't want to start on PowerShell to deal w uploading a single file.

Comment: ok, well storage explorer is the easiest, cheapest way to do it. I suggest posting a question about the issues you had so we can assist.

Comment: @Sam  Thank you for helping out! Posted the Azure Storage Explorer issue to thread: http://serverfault.com/q/804279/13716

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) to upload blobs to storage. If you upload a Page Blob which is sparse, it has an advantage of not uploading chunks with null data in them.