# Azure Storage Explorer: Error "ENOTFOUND" -- how to solve?

Tags: azure

I use Azure blob storage for downloadable files.

It works great, but I am forced to use a commercial tool to upload files.

Below shows how azure cloud explorer chokes, where the commercial azure manager works great. (I wanted to get into the storage account properties to review, but when I start the tool, the whole UI is hung and all I can do is close the app.)

How to get azure cloud explorer working?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you adding the storage account, by right clicking storage accounts and going to "Attach External Storage" or by going to the user icon and adding your user account for Azure?

Comment: @Sam I grabbed my azure storage access key from the azure portal and put it into the tool (This was days ago, don't recall all steps, but it was by putting in a url and a key, as I recall)

Comment: What data centre is this storage account in? It's not in China or Germany is it?

Comment: 1) this isn't the place for subjective rants - I edited them out, as they are not relevant to the question. 2) seems like you're specifically asking about a potential bug in a specific tool (as you mention that Management Studio, the commercial tool, works, and Storage Explorer throws an `ENOTFOUND` error). Maybe it's best to address this directly with the app creators (the app has a feedback link in the lower-left).

Comment: @samsmith I would suggest logging into the tool with your Azure account, rather than adding storage account keys directly. This has always worked fine for me. If your accessing storage in one of the trusted partner regions (so China or Germany) then this will likely cause this problem. If your not then try logging in directly and see if that works.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139415/why-is-azure-returning-404-resource-not-found-in-response-to-a-put-blob-request